# python input remembering past inputs incorrectly

Tags: python

I have been working on a problem for hours now and can't find out why it's not working. My code is basically finished except for one error that I can't get rid of. The problem is from the introduction to Python MIT course on edx. It's problem set 4 problem 6.

```
uinput = -1
hand = -1
while True:
    uinput = input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game:')
    if uinput == 'n':
        hand = dealHand(HAND_SIZE)
        playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
    elif uinput == 'r' and hand == -1:
        print('You have not played a hand yet. Please play a new hand first!')
    elif uinput == 'r' and hand != -1:
        playHand(hand, wordList, HAND_SIZE)
    elif uinput not in ('n', 'r', 'e'):
        print("Invalid command.")
        playGame(wordList)
    else:
        break
    print('')
```

This is the code it calls other functions but I don't think it's that important. The issue I have is that when I press 'e' it should fall through to the break and come out of the loop. It does this the first time I press 'e' but if I press any other key before that, it increments and I need to press 'e' that many times for it to actually break. For example if I press 'x' twice before i press 'e' I will need to press 'e' three times in total for it to reach the break. E.g. xxeee break. While trying to debug I saw that it even changes the uinput value back to 'x' like it's emptying a stack or something. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is this function of yours called playHand()? If you repeatedly call playHand() it'll start to stack up, requiring you to break each of the loop stack. If you remove the calls to playHand, dealHand, or playGame you'll see that your if/elif/else works normally.

Comment: this function is playGame() and im calling dealHand() and playHand(). I kind of need to call those functions for it to work, there isnt another way ? the specifications for the problem also ask for those functions to be called

Comment: Removing the calls to playHand, dealHand, and playGame is part of the debugging process to check if your if/else code works on its own. You can add the calls back one by one to see if one of the function calls triggers your bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function is called playGame(), there's a bug here:

```
elif uinput not in ('n','r', 'e'):
    print("Invalid command.")
    playGame(wordList)
```

You are calling playGame again when you press 'x'. This stacks another loop on top of your current `playGame` loop. Try removing the call to `playGame(wordList)` and it should fix your bug.

Comment: yes thats right, that removes the issue of pressing values other than 'n' and 'r' and having that problem which is enough to satisfy  the problems requirements. but it still happens when first pressing 'n' and then trying to get out of it pressing 'e'. is this avoidable ?

Comment: Check if your dealHand() or playHand() includes another call to playGame().

Comment: your right playHand() had another call to playGame(). I'm still quite new to python so didn't know about this problem. thank you for your help.